# How to create invisible space until a new line?

Tags: c

I am a beginner of C language. I was recently writing a  program to print a histogram of the number of instances of a character in an input. Printing the histogram horizontally is easy, but vertically is a challenge.

Please have a look at the following code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    /*THIS IS JUST A SAMPLE OF WHAT I WANT TO ASK*/
    int occurrence = 5;
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<occurrence;i++){
        printf("\t*\n");
    }




}
```

For an example, say any letter occurs 5 times. So I have set the occurrence to 5. And I am printing the bar in the form of asterisks. Now through this code, I am able to print an histogram containing 5 asterisks. But the thing is if I want to print other elements, like the x and y axis, the code creates a **\n** character. So if I write the code to print other elements, they start printing from the next line. So I figured out something else.

Now read this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    /*THIS IS JUST A SAMPLE OF WHAT I WANT TO ASK*/
    int instances = 5;
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<instances;i++){
        printf("\t*\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t");
    }




}
```

Now what I did is depending on the size of the output screen, I created 9 tab characters so that the next asterisk moves on to the next line without printing any **\n** character.

Now the main question: **IS THERE ANY OTHER WAY TO CREATE INVISIBLE SPACES UNTIL THE NEXT THING TO BE PRINTED MOVES ON TO THE NEXT LINE?**

This question might be stupid but if there is a solution, it will be best for me.

NOTE: If there is no such method of creating blank spaces then please suggest a good way to create a vertical histogram. If someone wants an improvisation in the question, I am ready to do it.

Thanks for the help!

***Outputs::***

If I use the first code and I make other chart elements using *printf*  statements, this is the output::
[image: OUTPUT]

Now can you see that the bar made of asterisks is not aligned with the x and y axis. This happens due to the **\n** character.

Comment: You don't need to print spaces until the end of the line. Just print `\n` after after you print the last element on a line.

Comment: But if I do that, I will not be able to print other elements of the histogram in alignment with the bars.

Comment: Can you give an example of required output demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Now is it fine?(I uploaded the image of the output)

Comment: It isn't guaranteed that the output will continue on the next line after the terminal width is exceeded. Some terminals might just print it outside the right edge, and maybe make the view horizontally scrollable, maybe not.

Comment: I am not talking about the input.. I am talking about output... That image is of the output.....

Comment: KK please help and thanx!!

Comment: Obviously you could simply use spaces instead of tabs, but I think what you really need is some dedicated terminal printing library like `ncurses` that mastov made an answer about. That way you can define exactly where (in which row and column) you want to output stuff.

Comment: Hmmm I will see what it is..... Thanx a lot to all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of hacking around with spaces yourself, you might want to look into a library that handles all that graphical stuff for you. For example, [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) is a pretty decent library to do pseudo-graphical output on a console. However, "ncurses" seems to be for Unix only, but there may be other libraries for Windows.

If using a library is not an option, I'd suggest to work with a 2-dimensional character buffer (that you treat like a bitmap) instead of writing things directly to the console. It's a lot less "fiddling around". Just watch out to truncate your buffer line size to the console line size before printing, in order to avoid automatic line breaks where you don't want them.

Comment: It sounds like your answer is correct, but I mentioned that I am a beginner.  I dont know anything about ncurses. But thanx!!

Comment: I haven't programmed with ncurses, either. What I am saying is: You are probably getting into a hell of a mess trying to do this stuff for yourself. Find a library for that helps you with that.

Comment: There is a "Histogram" widget for the "curses" (not "ncurses") library: http://freeware.sgi.com/Installable/cdk-4.9.10.html - however, that seems to be only for Unix (or maybe Cygwin under Windows). Does that matter?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use curses library, for example if you have found a printing terminal in a museum and want that your program can work on it, you have to reverse the problem.

You **must** print line by line if you do not use a graphic library. So your program could look like :

- compute the occurence of characters
- compute the maximum occurence
- for each line from max occurence to 0

  - compute a line for every character printing a space (not reached)
  - for each character

    - if the occurence is greater than the line index put a mark at correct place in the line
  - print the line

That's the algo, actual coding is left as exercice for the reader :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to think about having a two dimensional array. Start by filling it with spaces. Then replace the spaces with the character you want to print at the correct index.  Using two for loops, traverse the array in order to print. Print a new line at the end of the row. Changing the order of the index changes a vertical/horizontal print. Negatives are

1. having to keep the whole thing in memory.
2. Needing multiple passes. One to set the characters and another to print.

Comment: There is no need for that. All the information this needs is in his histogram.

Comment: @Jongware: But the algorithm becomes much more comprehensible, if you do it like that. Maybe for now it's still feasible to do it directly, but the more complex the drawing, the more useful the buffer.